# Difference between : and ! in julia dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am confusing with difference between **:** and **!** on Julia dataframe.

For example, here is a dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame(Data1 = rand(5), Data2 = rand(5));
```

Than, both operations which are,

```
df[:, 1]
```

AND

```
df[!,1]
```

returns same result on Julia dataframe.

Is there any difference between **!** and **:** ?